# Recyclerview is not showing any data which i have in firebase. Iam able to retrieve the data

Tags: android

HISTOROBJECT.CLASS

```
public class HistoryObject{
private String mName;
private String mImageUrl;

public HistoryObject(){

}
public HistoryObject(String Name, String Image) {
    this.user = Name;
    this.msg = Image;
}

private String user, msg;

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String Name) {
    this.msg = Name;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String Image) {
    this.user = Image;
}
```

}

HISTORYADAPTER.CLASS

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<HistoryObject> mUploads;

public HistoryAdapter (Context cx, List<HistoryObject> uploads){
    mContext = cx;
    mUploads = uploads;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listofitems, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    HistoryObject historyObject  = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(historyObject.getUser());
    Picasso.get().load(historyObject.getMsg())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.spapic);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size() ;
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView spapic;
     public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameofspa);
         spapic =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spapic);

     }
}
```

}

HOMEPAGE.CLASS

```
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BeautyCenters");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               // Log.d("SPAA", "VALUE IS " +dataSnapshot) ;
                Log.d("SPAA", "postsnap IS " +postSnapshot) ;

                HistoryObject upload = postSnapshot.getValue(HistoryObject.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mHistoryAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(HomePage.this, mUploads);

            mHistoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHistoryAdapter);
            mHistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Iam able to retrieve data and can see all list in logcat but it is not displaying in recyclerview. I also want to retrieve the images from the firebase. iam able to show the adapter but the text is not showing in that adapter instead it is blank and also the picture

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten to add a LayoutManager to your RecyclerView? I can't see one in the snippet that you posted, and in this case your RecyclerView won't be displaying any data.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before.
Try moving:

```
mHistoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHistoryAdapter);
mHistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

out of the listener class to the bottom of `onCreate`.

If that doesn't work make sure you have this code added:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.startListening();
        }
    }
```

If it is still not working then provide a link of your project and I will play around with it.

Comment: Additionally, you haven't provided a `LayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView` either. Without a `LayoutManager`, a `RecyclerView` will not show any data. See the following link for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager

Comment: i have in the code as         mHistoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: @AyeshaIsrar Just checked my notifications. I know it a long time ago hope you fixed your problem if not then let me know and I will try to help you.